# Equation trouble in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

Keep getting a message:

`! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \left 
l.70 \end{frame}`

when running the R markdown file below (in RStudio). I have spent a few hours pulling my hair out trying to figure out why? The equation renders in the preview.

```
---
title: "Compile Please"
output: beamer_presentation
---

## This Equation is Poison for Rmd

$$ f(x) = \left( 1 + \frac{x}{m - \alpha} \right) ^ \left( x \right) $$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be picky about spaces there.  This "tighter" version with explicit parens to protect that exponentiated works here:

```
$$ f(x) = \left( 1 + \frac{x}{m - \alpha} \right)^{\left( x \right)} $$
```